# Redirect occurring in IFrame

Tags: iframe

I have an affiliate URL that I want to put into an IFrame, so that when user's get to my IFrame page that affiliate cookie is dropped on their computer. However, the affiliate URL is not the actual product's page, but rather it redirects to the product page after the cookie is dropped. When it redirects to the product page, the IFrame is breaking out. Is there anything I can do so that when the affiliate URL redirects, it still stays on that same IFrame page?

Comment: Please provide more information and some code of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can write some javascript to prevent frame-busting, as described in this wonderful blog post by Jeff Atwood:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/06/we-done-been-framed.html

I've written a function that does this for one of my own web apps. It will prevent busting for only a specified amount of time, so the user can still navigate away from the page if he wants.

```
function preventBusting (time, frame) {
  var prevent_bust = 0;
  window.onbeforeunload = function () { prevent_bust++ };

  var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
    if (prevent_bust > 0) {
        prevent_bust -= 2;
        window.location.assign(url_204);    
        frame.text("This site does not allow framing.");
    }
  }, 1);

  setTimeout(function () {
    window.clearInterval(intervalID);
  }, time);
}
```

You should call this function right after you add the iFrame to the page. In this case, 'time' is the amount of time in milliseconds to prevent busting for, and 'frame' is a jQuery reference to the iframe, so it can be replaced with some text if busting is attempted. You'll need a URL that returns 204 as well, which is stored in the 'url_204' variable here.